# How to convert 2 unsigned 16bit integers into a signed 32bit integer in Perl

Tags: perl, type-conversion

I have a device that is able to send me data only as *unsigned* 16bit registers, using Perl.

I have to take 2 registers and make a 32 bit *signed* integer out of them.

My challenge is to represent a negative value having two positives.

Comment: Use pack/unpack

Answer (score 5):

Method 1:

```
my $int32 = unpack('l>', pack('nn', $hi16, $lo16));
```

Method 2:

```
my $int32 = ( $hi16 << 16 ) | $lo16;
$int32 -= 2**32 if $int32 >= 2**31;
```

For example,

```
use feature qw( say );

my $hi16 = 0xFFFF;
my $lo16 = 0xFFFD;
say $hi16;              # 65535
say $lo16;              # 65533

{
   my $int32 = unpack("l>", pack("nn", $hi16, $lo16));
   say $int32;          # -3

}

{
   my $int32 = ( $hi16 << 16 ) | $lo16;
   $int32 -= 2**32 if $int32 >= 2**31;
   say $int32;          # -3
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use `CORE::say` if you use `-E` command line switch instead of `-e`.

Comment: `-E` isn't forward-compatible. Since it enables all features, code that currently runs under `-E` might not on a later version of Perl.